# Create a folder in bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to create a folder inside the gcp bucket?

I tried using the below command but got an error.

```
  gsutil cp -r ./my-folder gs://bucket-name/my-folder/
```

or

```
    gsutil cp -r /my-folder gs://bucket-name/my-folder/
```

gcloud command:

```
gcloud scp -r /my-folder gs://bucket-name/my-folder/
```

I googled a bit and learned that gsutil and gcloud doesn't support to create a folder. Then how do we create a folder? is there any other way apart from using the gcp console?

Comment: Folders does not exist! https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Comment: gsutil cp command used to perform a copy operation right?. In my case, I am trying to create a new folder inside the bucket (e.g. bucket-name/folder1/folder2/

Comment: Again, folders do not exist! Read carefully the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As “Guillaume blaquiere” mentioned, “Folders” does not exist within GCS.

According to GCS [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders), GCS does not have a concept of "**Folders**" as the file path is just part of the name of the file and the GCS Console and gsutil internally constructs a **hierarchical representation**.

> Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders
> don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. If you create an object
> named **folder1/file.txt** in the bucket **your-bucket**, the path to
> the object is **your-bucket/folder1/file.txt**, but there is no folder
> named **folder1**; instead, the string **folder1** is part of the
> object's name.

However, you can try different commands in the **gsutil** environment.You can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders) for a list of available commands depending upon the requirement.

GCS has no notion of folders at present. The folder objects you see were created by clients (like gsutil and cloud console), essentially as markers so they can support creating a "folder" and then seeing it in a subsequent listing operation.

It's worth noting that the UI (i.e. Cloud console) has a "Create Folder" button which creates a zero byte object **mydirectory/** and not a real folder/directory, but it provides a placeholder for the name space.

**Update :**

> is it possible to move files from one folder to another folder within
> the same bucket?

Yes, you can use the below command to transfer data between folders.

```
gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/oldprefix gs://my_bucket/newprefix
```

If you have a large number of files to move,you might want to use the `gsutil -m` option, to perform a multi-threaded/multi-processing move:

```
gsutil -m mv gs://my_bucket/oldprefix gs://my_bucket/newprefix
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :). One question : Since GCS does not support folders in the traditional sense, instead offering a hierarchical representation, is it possible to move files from one folder to another folder within the same bucket?

Comment: Small correction in the above comment : it's not possible to move the files right?

Comment: I have updated my answer along with the above query.You can refer the mentioned link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-groups-of-objects for more details.